# How to upload a file from the user's system using firefox addon sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to Javascript and Firefox addon programming.

I am making an add-on with the Add-on SDK that logs some information about user browsing activities. I use the [`file` API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/api-utils/file.html) with some hard coded file names.

Now I want to analyze those log files on the server side but I don't want the user to go through the process of locating the files and uploading them manually. I want to provide a button to the user; onclicking which those files will be automatically uploaded to the server.

This automatic uploading functionality is quiet vital for the entire project since it is a study oriented project and it will be very hard to get data from the user if he'll have to upload it manually.

Comment: The link does not work anymore, and there is no reference to a "file" module on the API docs (API ver. 1.14). Is there a corresponding low-level API?

Answer (score 4):

Actual file upload (via `multipart/form-data`) is rather complicated to achieve but since you are controlling the server side - why not accept a regular POST request where the file data is in one of the form fields? So your code sending data to the server could look like this:

```js
var file = require("sdk/io/file");
var {Request} = require("sdk/request");

var params = {};
params.log = file.read("c:\\foo\\bar.log", "b");
params.additional = "some additional form field";

Request({
  url: "https://example.com/uploadlog",
  content: params,
  onComplete: function(response)
  {
    console.log("Request sent");
  }
}).post();
```

And you can put up a button anywhere that will trigger this code.

Comment: Is there any limit on the size of the data that i can send using post?

Comment: @Shatu: Only what you define on the server.

Comment: file module does not seem to exist anymore. Do you know of any replacement?

Comment: @Bora: It still exists: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.html. You might have to use the full name now however, I've adapted the example.